# Ember-data 1.13 metadataFor deprecated

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I used `store.metadataFor` but since 1.13, it’s deprecated. I have to use `records.get('meta')` but it always returns `undefined` (`metadataFor` works well).

Here’s my code:

```
this.store
  .findAll('user')
  .then(function (users) {
    console.log(users.get('meta'));
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a meta key?

Comment: Yes I am. the `store.metadataFor...` works well.

Comment: I'm using now the 1.13.8 version and `users.get('meta')` works well.

Comment: I don't understand your comments, I use ember data 1.13.8 and store.metadataFor works while model.get('meta') returns undefined.